How do I count html class elements on other page using js
I have a static portfolio website without database, I want to count no. of products on one page and display it on another one .
Right now I have come up with this
<script>
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
    const count = elements.length;
    document.getElementById("Count_exec_chair").innerHTML = count;
</script>

But This only works within same page . I want to count products on 3 different pages and display them on 4th one.
(Context : It's a small furniture company's website ,  they have added 15-20 Products of 4 categories Manually in Divs using  and 
Now They want me to make code so that whenever someone add product the count in menu increases .)

I have a vague idea that local storage might be useful but it wont work if someone visits the second page before first one

After getting your value, store it in localStorage and on the other page that needs the value, retrieve it. Also, don't use innerHTML to store strings that don't have HTML in them. Use .textContent instead.

How do you post your products on page from database ? or using products stored in JS object ?

but in my scenario people will visit display count page first and then go to the page with the elements

You are going to need some form of server-side data storage.

A bad but fairly easy solution would be to put a script on page 4 that fetches and parses pages 1, 2, 3, and counts the elements.  It’s bad because it would fire every time someone loads page 4 instead of every time the inventory is updated, but possibly not that noticeable, especially if pages 1,2,3 are already in the browser cache.

In the OP it isn't certain how a user selects a <div> and how to keep track of said <div> so the example I've provided uses <input type="checkbox"> as a means for the user to select an item.
// All of a <form>'s <fieldset>, <input>, and <output> into an array
const items = Array.from(document.forms[0].elements);
// Iterating through the array, return the index of selected items or nothing
const cnt = items.flatMap((item, index) => item.checked ? index : [])

Each page has a <fieldset> - (document.forms[0].elements[0]), and four <input type="checkbox"> - (document.forms[0].elements[1 - 4]), and the last page has an <output> - (document.forms[0].elements[5]) as well.
Each page has a number value assigned to variable idx 0 to 3. Each page is also represented as an object literal: {} stored within an array that's stored as a string within localStorage. Each object literal has two properties:
{
  selected: [1, 2, 3, 4] // index numbers of selected `<input>`
  total: 4 // total of selected `<input>`
}

Any time a page is loaded the array of objects is retrieved from localStorage and the <input>s are checked according to the object's .selected property (ex. [2, 3] <input> 2 and 3 are checked). Anytime an <input> is checked (or unchecked) the corresponding index of that <input> is added to that page's object .selected array.
In addition, the last page's <output> will display the total sum of each object's total property every time it's loaded or if a user selects (or deslects) an <input>.
localStorage does not function in a SO Snippet so go here for a working example.


const key = 'count';

function getCount(key) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [{}, {}, {}, {}];
}

function getSelected() {
  const items = Array.from(document.forms[0].elements);
  return items.flatMap((item, index) => (item.checked ? index : []));
}

function setSelected() {
  const items = Array.from(document.forms[0].elements);
  const counts = getCount(key);
  counts[idx].selected.forEach((number) => (items[number].checked = true));
}

function addSelected() {
  const counts = getCount(key);
  const cnt = getSelected();
  counts[idx].selected = cnt;
  counts[idx].total = cnt.length;
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(counts));
}

function totalSelected() {
  const counts = getCount(key);
  const total = counts.reduce((sum, page) => sum + page.total, 0);
  document.forms[0].elements.grandTotal.value = total;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setSelected);
document.forms[0].addEventListener('change', addSelected);
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1 'Segoe UI';
}
menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <menu>
        <li><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Page 4</a></li>
      </menu>
    </nav>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label> Item 13 <input type="checkbox" /> </label>
        <label> Item 14 <input type="checkbox" /> </label>
        <label> Item 15 <input type="checkbox" /> </label>
        <label> Item 16 <input type="checkbox" /> </label>
        <label> Total: &nbsp;&nbsp;<output id="grandTotal"></output> </label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
      const idx = 3;
    </script>
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', totalSelected);
      document.forms[0].addEventListener('change', totalSelected);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




If you don't have access to a database or server, you may be able to use fetch(). For instance, if you put this in the console of this page, it should show how many elements have the -link--channel-name class on the Stack Overflow question page:
Note: Please be careful when copying and pasting code into the console. Make sure you are aware of what each line of code does.
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/')
 .then(result => result.text())
 .then(text => {
  var match = text.match(/class=["'][^"']*-link--channel-name[^"']*["']/g);
  if(match) console.log(`Matches found: ${match.length}`);
  else console.log(`Matches found: 0`);
});

I would provide a snippet, but fetch can be tricky. When attempting to use a snippet, the Stack Overflow CORS policy stopped it from working.
I should also mention that fetch will only work for you if the page you're trying to access has the class written in the HTML. This method cannot detect a class or elements that are added after the page loads. In this instance, if I search for the s-link class (links to questions) I get no matches.
If fetch does work for your website, here is what that code does:
// Send a fetch request to the disired url.
// If on your own domain, you might not have to use a full url.
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/')

 // Take the result of that request and retrieve the text from it (the HTML of the page).
 .then(result => result.text())

 .then(text => {
  // Take the text and search for the class using a regular expression.
  var match = text.match(/class=["'][^"']*-link--channel-name[^"']*["']/g);

  // Do something with the result.
  if(match) console.log(`Matches found: ${match.length}`);
  else console.log(`Matches found: 0`);
});


Don't use regular expressions to process HTML. Parse the HTML and use DOM methods.

That is a better idea. I haven't run into that problem, so I didn't have the best way to parse HTML. I might say that using a regular expression could help with performance, but it certainly isn't the best solution. You're right.
